# Performing pairwise calculation and outputting the result in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following phylogenetic tree and matrix of presence-absence data for several taxa in 3 sites:

```r
set.seed(020123)
tree_ <- phytools::pbtree(b = 1, n = 7)

matrix_ <- structure(
  c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  dim = c(3L, 7L),
  dimnames = list(c("site_1", "site_2", "site_3"),
  c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7"))
)
```

I'd like to compute the pairwise phylogenetic distance for all sites and store the results in an object of class `dist`.

I can compute the phylogenetic distance between two sites using the following functions:

```r
get_community_taxa <- function(x) {
  list(
    colnames(x)[x[1, ] == 1L],
    colnames(x)[x[2, ] == 1L]
  )
}

phylo_dist <- function(x, tree) {
  distance_mtx <- ape::cophenetic.phylo(tree)
  communities <- get_community_taxa(x)
  phylo_dist <- distance_mtx[
    communities[[1]],
    communities[[2]]
  ]
  if (length(phylo_dist) == 1L) {
    return(phylo_dist)
  }
  mean(c(
    apply(phylo_dist, 1, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    apply(phylo_dist, 2, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  ))
}
```

I've tried using the function above in combination with `combn` which gives me a vector of distances for each pair of sites:

```r
apply(
  combn(nrow(v), 2),
  MARGIN = 2,
  function(x) phylo_dist(matrix_[x, ], tree_)
)
#> [1] 1.276455 2.191359 3.045831
```

But I'm not sure how to output these values in a well structured matrix (see below).

Here's the desired output (object of class `dist`):

```
         site_1   site_2
site_2 1.276455         
site_3 2.191359 3.045831
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we could use `outer` here and convert to `dist`

```
out <- outer(seq_len(nrow(matrix_)), seq_len(nrow(matrix_)), 
     Vectorize(function(i, j) phylo_dist(matrix_[c(i, j),], tree_)))
dimnames(out) <- list(row.names(matrix_), row.names(matrix_))
```

-output

```
> as.dist(out)
         site_1   site_2
site_2 1.276455         
site_3 2.191359 3.045831
```